# Crawling a specific information from a URL in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

The simplest way to crawl HTML tables is using `pandas.read_html(url)`. For the following URL, I get all of its tables

```
import pandas as pd
url="http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=3944788.PN.&OS=PN/3944788&RS=PN/3944788"
df=pd.read_html(url)
```

From the above URL I just want this specific information.

```
Current U.S. Class: 235/54F
```

Considering above `df` as a list I have written following code to get this specific information

```
myitem="Current U.S. Class:"
for i in range(len(df)):
    if myitem in str(df[i]):
        ClassTitle=''.join(df[i][0])
        ClassNumber=''.join(df[i][1])

if ';' in ClassTitle:
    ClassTitle=ClassTitle.rsplit(':')
    print(ClassTitle[0])
if ';' in ClassNumber:
    ClassNumber=ClassNumber.rsplit(';')
if ',' in ClassTitle:
    ClassTitle=ClassTitle.rsplit(',')
    print(ClassTitle[0])
if ',' in ClassNumber:
    ClassNumber=ClassNumber.rsplit(',')
```

But this sometimes works fine for some URL's and sometimes it also includes other class details as well as `Current CPC Class` and `Current International Class`. I have also tried `BeautifulSoap` using `View Page Source` feature but I am confused to mention class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using BeautifulSoup**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=3944788.PN.&OS=PN/3944788&RS=PN/3944788')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table')[4]
result = table.find('tr').text
print(result)
# Current U.S. Class: 235/54F
```

**Explanation**

The table you are after, is the 5th table in the page. `find_all('table')` returns a list of all the tables. So, `find_all('table')[4]` will give the 5th table.

The text you want, is located in the first row, or the first `tr` tag. `table.find('tr')` returns the first `tr` tag found inside the table.

Finally, `.text` gives you the text inside the tag.

Comment: Is there any direct way to get the table number containing the desired information because some of  url's contain this information in some other table number. One solution can be as First I have to search "Current US Class" string in all table and get the table number containing this information but I want to know is there any direct way for that? @Keyur Potdar

Comment: You can use the [`find_parent()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-parents-and-find-parent) method for that. Try doing it yourself. If you are unable to do it, you can ask a new question here on SO if no one has already asked that. You won't get the table number, but you'll directly get the table.

Comment: Sure brother Thankyou so much for your kindness.